# when I use gimp to make a puzzle pattern the next time it is grayed out and I cannot use it

Tags: gimp

When I use Gimp to make a puzzle pattern and try to do it again with more pieces the jigsaw is grayed out and I cannot use it. Even if I restart Gimp the same thing happens. How can I get around this problem?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

[Jigsaw](https://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-jigsaw.html) GIMP plug-in only works on RGB images. Did you change the image to greyscale or indexed?

Comment: It's possible that this answer might actually provide a solution to Garry's question. Unfortunately Garry hasn't visited the site since the day when he posted the question, so we may never know if it solved the problem.